# Nginx virtual block on Mac pointing to localhost's index.php

Tags: php, macos, nginx, server

I am configuring virtual host to serve .localhost domain on my mac. But when I open "project.localhost" in my browser it shows the same page as, browsing the index of localhost. (ps: I've also configured dnsmasq and /etc/hosts). (trying to serve index.php)

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024; }


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    client_max_body_size 50M;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root   html;

        location / {
            # root   html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            # root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            # root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    include servers/*; }
```

and here is sites-available:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen project.localhost:80;
        server_name project.localhost;

        location / {
            root html/project.localhost/public_html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root html/project.localhost/public_html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

and here is dnsmasq.conf:

```
address=/.localhost/127.0.0.1
```

and here is /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   project.localhost www.project.localhost
```

but when I browse project.localhost in my browser it shows same page as localhost/index.php. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should the `server_name` value be `project.localhost` and not `project.local`?

Comment: I cannot see if the file in `sites-available` has been included into your Nginx configuration. You are including files from the `servers` directory (see the last line). Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files and ensure that your `server` block with the correct `server_name` is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Richard mentioned in the comment section I was able to solve the issue by including `sites-available/*.conf`: `include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf`, just before  `include server/*` into my nginx.conf. Thank you @Richard